# key usage attributes and enhanced key usage attributes overwritten with CA template properties

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

I have generated a csr with key usage attributes and enhanced key usage attribute but when we sign with the computer template in Microsoft CA, it overwrites the attributes in the CSR, how do i maintain the attributes in csr while signing via microsoft CA ?

Comment: You have to duplicate existing template and create a new one that satisfies your requirements. Microsoft CA will ignore most extensions from CSR and use ones configured in template.

Answer (score 1):

As Crypt32 mentioned in the comments, the enhanced key usage as well as other certificate attributes need to be configured in a template on the Microsoft CA server for a particular signing certificate.

By design, the CA will ignore attributes and extension that are not configured for a template.

[Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b63c7a51-a2f3-474c-a47c-23ae9f0e7131/csr-key-usage-is-overriden-by-the-ca-template?forum=winserversecurity) is a thread on a similar topic for reference. An extract of the key point is listed below.

> ...The Web Server certificate template has a specific Key Usage
>   configured, and you cannot override it during a request. As stated
>   earlier, someone with privileges in the network will have to duplicate
>   the Web server certificate template, and set the Key Usage that you
>   wish. In addition, permissions must be set to allow either you or the
>   computer account (you are not clear on where this is going) the Read
>   and Enroll permissions.